# Select a row multiple times from table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables in mysql, one is user and one is item

**table1 user**

```
id   name
----------
1    Peter
2    Roy
3    Mary
```

**table2 item**

```
id  name  owner1 owner2
 1   pen     1       2
 2   shoes   2       3
```

Each item have 2 owner, there user id will store in owner1 and owner2.
Now i want to select the name of owner in table2 when get all data in table2, so i want to select row(name) two time to get the name.

I try to use join statement to write sql statement but it not work.

How to write sql statement in this case?

The result list of my want

1. itemid  2.itemname  3.owner1 username  4.owner2 username

Comment: i want to select all data in table2 with owner name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not being very clear on what results you want, I am assuming you want the item and then the name of each user on the same row, you could just create two joins for each owner:

```
SELECT item.id, item.name, user_one.name as owner1, user_two.name as owner2
FROM item
LEFT JOIN user AS user_one ON (user_one.id = item.owner1)
LEFT JOIN user AS user_two ON (user_two.id = item.owner2)
```

Comment: i wants select the name of owner in table2 when get itemid1  in table2,How to write sql statement?

Comment: Can you list the exact columns you want in your results? I don't quite understand what you are asking..

Comment: 1. itemid 2.itemname  3.owner1 username  4.owner2 username

Comment: I have added the item.id to the above reply. That query will return the data you need.

Comment: Sorry, I had an error in the query above please retry it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.id
     , i.name
     , u1.name owner1
     , u2.name owner2
  FROM item i
  JOIN user u1
    ON u1.id = i.owner1
  JOIN user u2
    ON u2.id = i.owner2;
```

Comment: if i want select the name of owner in table2 when get all data in table2,How to write sql statement?

Comment: If you have a different question, ask a different question, or edit the one above.

Answer (score 0):

Select the 2 owners' names of item 'pen':

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE id=1 or id=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join to user table two times:
SELECT item.name, owner1.name, owner2.name 
FROM items 
JOIN user owner1 ON item.owner1 = owner1.id
JOIN user owner2 ON item.owner2 = owner2.id